# How to set a value in a drop-down list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm facing a problem with setting a value in a drop-down list. The following is the code for my drop-down:

```
<select class="price-dropdown" ng-model="createCampaign.currency" ng-options="obj.id as obj.symbol for obj in config.currencies"></select>
```

Here is the object:

```
[Object, Object]
   0: Object
      id: "GBP"
      name: "GBP"
      symbol: "GBP"
      __proto__: Object
   1: Object
      id: "dollar"
      name: "Dollar"
      symbol: "$"
      __proto__: Object
   length: 2
   __proto__: Array[0]
```

It's setting 0, 1, 2 as the value instead of `id`.

I've looked at other questions but haven't been able to make any of the solutions work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Its setting the object Ordinal it seems. can you debug and edit in {obj.id} inside ng-options="obj.id as obj.symbol for obj in config.currencies"> to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/117/) for your problem. Over here it is having id as value.

Code Snippet:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select 
            ng-options="p.name as p.name for p in symbol"
            ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>
        {{ selectedPerson }}
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think a dropdown list must have a unique identifier among the list.. to identify the correct selection..look in this sample fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bvD2a/3/) it may help you..

```
<select class="span2" name="SelectedState" ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.id as state.name for state in states">    
   </select>
```

Controller code:

```
  $scope.states = [{
    id: 1, name: 'France'
  }, {
    id: 2, name: 'UK'
  }, {
     id: 3, name: 'Germany'
  }];  

$scope.selectedState = $scope.states[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

***This code will help to solve your problem please check it once***

```
$scope.colors = [
      {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'white', shade:'light'},
      {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
    ];

 <select name="value">
    <option ng-repeat="color in colors" value="{{color.name}}">
        {{color.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not bug, it's a feature. angularjs handles ngOptions and ngModel internally, this way it allows you to use any type of object as value in option rather than only strings. This [link](http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/) should help you :) Watch this tutorial this is shortcut for your problem.